# $('<tag />') breaks my highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

But

```
$('<tag></tag>')
```

doesn't.

The problem seems to come with the '/>' thing.

This is happening in gedit, aptana and scribes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My flavor of Vim happens to handle self-closing tags. In general, editor syntax highlighters use lexical rules, not semantic ones to figure out how to colorize. Since (X|HT)ML is not a regular language, it is pretty easy to fool them.

Indeed for just about any language, it is possible to generate a construction that will fool the highlighter. You may be able to find improved highlighters for `<your preferred editor/>` or you may just have to choose between "fast and mistaken" or "slow and precise"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("<tag />")
```

and see if that breaks highlighting too.

Comment: Yes, it does. And in all editors again.